# How do I calculate mean of a vector 'x' while excluding min and max values from the calculation?

Tags: r, mean, outliers

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to find the mean of vector x while excluding the lowest and highest numbers in the vector.
Thanks!

The answer should be `3.5`
I tried this and other ways but no luck!

```
mean(g,-which.min(g),-which.max(g))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`range()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/range) function to return a vector containing the minimum and maximum values of `x`.

Then subset `x` to exclude those values, and take the mean.

```r
mean(x[!x %in% range(x)]) # 3.5
```

Comment: Many thanks, SamR! It works!   Is there a way to accomplish the same task using the which function ?

Comment: You can do `mean(x[-which(x %in% range(x))])`

Answer (score 2):

This is built in to the default `mean` function.  To get rid of the top and bottom values, use `mean(x, trim = 1/length(x))`.  That takes one observation off the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `which` solution:

```
x <- sample(1:10)
x
[1]  7  1 10  5  4  3  8  2  9  6
x[-which(x == max(x) | x == min(x))]
[1] 7 5 4 3 8 2 9 6
mean(x[-which(x == max(x) | x == min(x))])
[1] 5.5
```